# How to read from pubsub source in parallel using dataflow

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-pubsub

I am very new to dataflow, I am looking to build pipeline which will use pubsub as source.

I have worked on streaming pipeline which has flink as streaming engine and kafka as source, in that we can set parallelism in flink to read messages from kafka so that message processing can happen in parallel instead of sequential.

I am wondering if same can be possible in pubsub->dataflow, or it will only read message in sequential order.

Comment: Imagine an Apache Beam "source transform" which receives data from an external source (Pub/Sub).  This will be the start of the DAG.  The notion of Beam is to own and optimize the work.  If we read here https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/subscriber ... we find that Pub/Sub is inherently highly parallel.  Does Beam provide for parallelization of input sources as well as workers for DoFn work?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [PubSubToBigQuery](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowTemplates/blob/master/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/teleport/templates/PubSubToBigQuery.java) pipeline. This uses PubSub as a source, this will read data in parallel. Multiple threads will be each reading a message off of pubsub and handing it off to downstream transforms for processing, by default.

Please note that the PubSubToBQ pipeline can also be [run as a template pipeline](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/executing-templates), which works well for many users. Just launch the pipeline from the Template UI and set the appropriate parameters to point to your pub sub and BQ locations. Some users prefer to use it that way. But this depends on where you want to store your data.